# Protein content in sprouted beans

Tags: botany, proteins, food, nutrition

I have checked on Wikipedia which says that sprouted mung beans has way less protein than normal one, while on web you will find articles saying sprouted beans are best, which is true, how do I eat unbaked mung bean anyway without any processing they are so hard. Does soaking moon beans overnight really reduce protein content drastically ?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**:

- 1. Yes the legume seed protein content decrease when it germinates.

but still;

- 2. The sprouting seed is healthier.

**Long answer**:

Yes it is true that after germinating some of the protein decrease. It is mostly due to breakdown, transport and consumption of protein stored in seed. All [fabaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae) (former Leguminosae-*sensu-stricto*) members use a large amount of protein storage, such as [Vicillin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicilin)s, [Legumin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legumin)s, etc in their seed [cotyledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotyledon)s . All edible [true-pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legume)s , including [pea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pea) , [mung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_bean), etc belong to fabaceae.  When the seed germinates, theses proteins breaks down into simple amino acids and small peptides, and get reallocated*.  In addition, *a part of this work as food (respiratory substrate) through amino acid oxidation*  **.

> Fig-1
>   [image: Protein mobilization in seeds simplified diagram]
>   Protein mobilization in seeds... simplified.
>   Source... *
>
> Fig-2
>   [image: the process in Mung bean seed].
>   The cellular process of protein mobilization in `Mung bean` cotyledon. 
>   Source ... *

---

We are commonly advised to eat sprouting seeds not for their protein content (we get the major portion of protein from daily major foods like meat, fish, eggs, leafy vegetables, etc.); but it is for the vitamin content.

[This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4499388/) says

> " Mung bean sprout produces several kinds of hepatoprotective compounds such as flavonoid and chlorogenic acid."

There are also many papers related to sprouting mung bean; such as this but I do not have full access to them (sorry for that), such as [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0308814604000330), [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2621.1975.tb02254.x/full) etc.

---

> Reference
>
> 1. `*` Protein Storage and Utilization in Seeds; by Rod Casey, J.Derek Bewly and John S. Greenwood. Published as a chapter in a book, *Plant Metabolism*, Edited by Dennis, Turpin, Lefbvre, Lyzell. Second Edition.
> 2. `**` Amino Acid Catabolism in Plants; Tatjana M. Hildebrandt , Adriano Nunes Nesi, Wagner L. Araújo, Hans-Peter Braun ([NCBI-PMC](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26384576)) ([Full-text Free Open access link](http://www.cell.com/molecular-plant/fulltext/S1674-2052(15)00366-4))